# how to read an image into a single pixel value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, centering

I have two png images, I want to read each of them (the entire image) into a single pixel value instead of a multiple value matrix in python. How do I do that? I have no code to include here.

I haven't tried anything yet as I am not sure how to convert them into single pixel values. Everything I have seen so far reads or converts an image into a multiple value matrix or column or rows. But no single values so far. I can not average the multiple values cause I will need to use that average for centering the data.

Comment: It's unclear what you want that single pixel value to represent. Obviously you cannot compress potentially millions of pixels into the space of one pixel, but if you're trying to get the average or centroid of an image, you could read the image pixels one by one and accumulate the values.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do and what you hope to achieve. Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. Thank you.